# Formatting toString method

Tags: java, string, methods, printf

I have a `toString()` method from my class that takes the information from the object and puts it into a string to be printed.

This is what it should look like:

```
Susan         70     <Average   C
Alexander     80     >Average   B
```

, but I'm having trouble formatting my `toString()` method. This is what it looks like this right now which is very unorganized.

```
public String toString() {

    return ("\n" + fullName + 
            "            " + relativeScore +
            "            " + testScore);

}
```

I would normally use printf, but since it's a return statement I can't use it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what's the output you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.format` method returns a new String object, so you can use it rather than `printf`, for instance:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s\t%3d\t%s", fullName, relativeScore, testScore);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could simply use `String#format`, for example:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %d %10s %5s", "Susan", 70, "<Average", "C"));
```

Which outputs

```
Susan      70   <Average     C
```

For more details have a look at [this example](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) and [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.format()` and do it just like you would do with `printf()`

```
return String.format("whatever comes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

you're doing it wrong way. Susan is 5 letter word and Alexander is 9 letter word. So if susan is followed by 10 white spaces then alexander should be followed by 10-9+5= 6 white spaces. You should consider the length of fullname in your code.

Comment: If the values are from two different instance of the same class, how would the OP do that?